# Check for a certain MQTT response and do something

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I'm a little stuck here. I want to check for a specific MQTT response in javascript and do something with it, but my code is failing. Can anybody help here?

The application receives JSON strings as following:

```
[{"key":"volume","value":"4"}]
```

I use this code to check for a message:

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  //message = JSON.parse(message);
  console.log('Data: ' + message);
  var strin = [{key:'volume', value: 4}]
  if(message == strin) {
    console.log('Specific');
  }else {
    // test
  }
})
```

But as soon as i send a specific message via POST to the server, i don't get the specific response...

Anybody here with some insight?

Answer (score 0):

The message object is not just the payload, it has more fields, what you need is the payload, which will be a String, not a JSON object to start with:

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {   
  var payload = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
  console.log('Data: ' + payload);
  var strin = [{key:'volume', value: 4}];
  if(payload == strin) {
    console.log('Specific');
  } else {
    // test
  }
})
```

Also it is not easy to do **deep** object comparison in Javascript, the quick and dirty solution seams to be as follows:

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    var payload = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
    console.log('Data: ' + payload);
    var strin = [{key:'volume', value: 4}];
    if(JSON.stringify(payload) == JSON.stringify(strin)) {
        console.log('Specific');
    } else {
        // test
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I see now that my method is not foolproof. I'll test your solution out :)